# How to set an image into an UIImageView without any quality loss and getting the average colour of the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

I want to do something like this. Im selecting maximum 8 images from my phone photo gallery. And I set it into several image views. Those image views are same size. But my images are different sizes.So some images looks so ugly because of stretching.

So How can I set the image inside a `UIImageView` without any quality loss.

Also How can I set the `UIImageview` bckground colour as the average colour of the current image which inside of that `UIImageView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` like this...

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

And your image name should be `image@2x.png` if possible to get the original quality

**UPDATE**

If you are getting image from the image picker, use this..

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage * pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageView setImage:pickedImage];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

**imageView frame 320x200 pixels with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`**

[image]

**imageView frame 320x200 pixels with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFilt`**

[image]

Comment: im selecting images from the phone. So how to get a name for those?

Comment: Now Im confuse with the UIViewContentModeScaleToFill and UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit It should be possible to scale vertical images too. What should I use out of these two?

Comment: @user2889249 If the image that you picked from the image picker is smaller than the imageView and you use UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, then your image will be stretched. But if you use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit the image will not be stretched.

Comment: @user2889249 see my screenshot on my updated answer and you'll see what I mean :)

Comment: Yeas @Ty_ This is what I wanted exactly :) Thank you so much. Its working nicely

Answer (score 2):

You can use the contentMode property to scale your image accordingly.

For example,

```
image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

This will scale your image to the size of your UIImageView frame.

If you're loading images in from a server, you will have to load the data according to UIImageJPEGRepresentation. That takes two parameters, the image and quality.

For example,

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

Where 1.0 is the highest quality :)

Good luck!

Comment: but this still not scal the verticle images properly. How can I scale verticle images?

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit